# How to push key and value to an empty hash with a loop in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I want to use Bing search results for my webpage. To use their json data I found this solution:

```
new_bing_results = bing_results[0][:Web]


result = { }


result[:title] = new_bing_results[0][:Title]
result[:description] = new_bing_results[0][:Description]
result[:url] = new_bing_results[0][:Url]
result[:display_url] = new_bing_results[0][:DisplayUrl]

result[:title1] = new_bing_results [1][:Title]
result[:description1] = new_bing_results [1][:Description]
result[:url1] = new_bing_results [1][:Url]
result[:display_url1] = new_bing_results [1][:DisplayUrl]

result[:title2] = new_bing_results [2][:Title]
result[:description2] = new_bing_results [2][:Description]
result[:url2] = new_bing_results [2][:Url]
result[:display_url2] = new_bing_results [2][:DisplayUrl]
```

....

```
          result
```

How can I create a loop that is doing the same thing 50 times without having to repeat the same code.

I tried this but only get errors:

```
new_bing_results = bing_results[0][:Web]
$i = 0
$num = 50
result2 = {}

while $i < $num do
    result[:title$i]  = new_bing_results[$i][:Title]
```

......

```
end

result
```

The problem is that I do not find a solution for adding my $i number to the key result[:title] as in the value new_bing_results[$i][:Title]

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
result = {}
50.times do |i|
  result["title#{i}".to_sym] = new_bing_results[i][:Title]
  result["description#{i}".to_sym] = new_bing_results[i][:Description]
  result["url#{i}".to_sym] = new_bing_results[i][:Url]
  result["display_url#{i}".to_sym] = new_bing_results[i][:DisplayUrl]
end
```

`50.times` will run from `0` to `49` and you can use interpolation to avoid the repetition.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast and precise answer. That has done the trick :)

Comment: You can accept the answer which worked for you and upvote the answers you think are proper

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.to_sym` method. For example:

```
new_bing_results =  [{Title: "Title"}]
result = {}
result["title#{i}".to_sym] = new_bing_results[i][:Title]
result
=> {:title0=>"Title"}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use string interpolation and then the to_sym method.

```
    result = {}
    50.times do |n|
      result["title#{n}".to_sym] = new_bing_results[n][:Title]
    end
```